# Feature engineering keywords for keras network

Tags: python, keras, tensorflow, feature-engineering

I am building a multi-label classifier, using the `keras` sequential API. My goal is to take an input of keywords 'cat', 'dog', 'rabbit' and apply a custom label.

My first attempt was to one hot encode all of the keywords, this works fine for training, but when doing online predictions - in another system the data processing becomes tough, as there is no easy way to maintain the positions of keywords on the input to the NN.

My idea is to therefore convert all the keywords to ints and feed this to the network. Is this feasible?

The data structure is as follows:

```
| label | keyword_array          |
| 123   | ['dog','cat', 'happy'] |
| 234   | ['sad','foot', 'fast'] |
```

New keywords are also constantly being added as the model is retrained, also an online prediction could have an unseen word.

EDIT:
Ideally I could use a system that given a string of words, or an list - would return some representation which I could feed into my network both for training and prediction.

Comment: Just an idea: Generate an integer by the sum of the position of a letter in the alphabet. This should give unique integers per word. Would this work?

Comment: @Peter thanks for that - would that be enough for the network to learn anything useful? I was planning to convert the keywords to vectors.

Comment: I think could probably work in a similar way like one-hot encoding, but ultimately it depends on testing. So it is really just an idea...